# ldd shows varied addresses on x86 Linux

Tags: linux, x86, fedora, powerpc, ldd

I am using `ldd` to show the dynamic library on Fedora/x86, and it shows different results each time it is used.

Is that expected?  Or is there an explanation?

I remember it shows a fixed result on PPC/Linux.

```
`ldd /bin/ls
 linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0x00e5b000)
 librt.so.1 => /lib/librt.so.1 (0x00c0c000)
 libselinux.so.1 => /lib/libselinux.so.1 (0x0095d000)
 libcap.so.2 => /lib/libcap.so.2 (0x00110000)
 libacl.so.1 => /lib/libacl.so.1 (0x00331000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x00115000)
 libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00bc9000)
 /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x009d2000)
 libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0x00680000)
 libattr.so.1 => /lib/libattr.so.1 (0x00447000)
ldd /bin/ls
 linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0x00f76000)
 librt.so.1 => /lib/librt.so.1 (0x00494000)
 libselinux.so.1 => /lib/libselinux.so.1 (0x0095d000)
 libcap.so.2 => /lib/libcap.so.2 (0x009e9000)
 libacl.so.1 => /lib/libacl.so.1 (0x00365000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x00732000)
 libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00b61000)
 /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x002a7000)
 libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0x002f0000)
 libattr.so.1 => /lib/libattr.so.1 (0x00447000)`
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Fedora uses [address space randomization](http://lwn.net/Articles/121845/) as part of its various security measures. `ldd` works by actually loading the shared objects and showing where they end up. Putting the two together results in the given observations.